# Understanding product $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be an indexed collection of nonempty sets, $X = \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$, and $\pi _\alpha: X \rightarrow X_\alpha$ the coordinate maps. If $M_\alpha$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$, what is the product $\sigma$-algebra on $X$?

I am reading a book, and it says that the product $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by 
$$
\{\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha): E_\alpha \in M_\alpha, \alpha \in A\}
$$

I was wondering:

1. Why isn't it simply $\prod _{\alpha \in A}M_\alpha$?
2. I am completely confused with this statement of the book, can anyone give a simple example to clarify what the book is trying to say?

Comment: It isn't $\prod_{\alpha\in A}M_\alpha$ because this need not be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: First of all, your definition actually agrees with their definition when the set $A$ is countable. I think the reason they define it that way is because when you want to define a measure on the product space you define it as a product of the measures i.e. for a product of two measure spaces: ($\mu\otimes\nu)(A\times B):=\mu(A)\nu(B)$. If you want to extend this to an infinite product, you need to ensure that you're only taking at most a countable product of real numbers on the RHS.

Comment: @Math1000 Presumably he means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that...

Comment: Please note that, even if $A$ is finite,  an element of $\prod _{\alpha \in A}M_\alpha$ is not a subset of $ \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$. So $\prod _{\alpha \in A}M_\alpha$ can not be (or generate) a $\sigma$-algebra on $ \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$. I think you meant to write: the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\prod _{\alpha \in A}E_\alpha : E_\alpha \in M_\alpha, \alpha \in A\}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please note that, even if $A$ is finite,  an element of $\prod _{\alpha \in A}M_\alpha$ is not a subset of $\prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$. So it can not be (or generate) a $\sigma$-algebra on $ \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$. I think you meant to write: the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\prod _{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha : E_\alpha \in M_\alpha, \alpha \in A\}$.

Let $M$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by 
$$
\{\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha): E_\alpha \in M_\alpha, \alpha \in A\}
$$
and $N$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by 
$$
\{\prod _{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha : E_\alpha \in M_\alpha, \alpha \in A\}
$$ 
First, as Tyr mentioned, if $A$ is (at most) countable, then $M=N$.  In the general case, we have $M\subseteq N$. In all cases, the product $\sigma$-algebra is the SMALLEST  $\sigma$-algebra that makes all the coordinate maps $\pi _\alpha$ measurables, and that is $M$. It is similar to the way we define product topology.

Why we want the product $\sigma$-algebra to be the SMALLEST  $\sigma$-algebra that makes all the coordinate maps $\pi _\alpha$ measurables ?

Because the smallest  $\sigma$-algebra that makes all the coordinate maps $\pi _\alpha$ measurables is precisely the only  $\sigma$-algebra on $ \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$ which makes the following proposition hold:

> Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a mensurable space and $f: X \to  \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$ then: $f$ is measurable IF AND ONLY IF , for all $\alpha \in A$, $\pi_\alpha \circ f$ is measurable.

Any $\sigma$-algebra on $ \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$ larger than $M$ (the product  $\sigma$-algebra) will result in the existence of $f$ which is not measurable but, for all $\alpha\in A$, $\pi_\alpha \circ f$ is measurable.

Any $\sigma$-algebra on $ \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$ smaller than $M$ (the product  $\sigma$-algebra) will result in the existence of a measurable $f$  such that there is  $\alpha\in A$, $\pi_\alpha \circ f$ is not measurable.

In fact, let $S$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $ \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$.

If $S \varsupsetneq M$, take $X= \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$ and $\Sigma=M$, then $Id: (\prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha,M) \to (\prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha, S) $ is NOT measurable, but, for all $\alpha\in A$, $\pi_\alpha \circ Id$ is measurable.

If $S \varsubsetneq M$, take $X= \prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$ and $\Sigma=S$, then $Id: (\prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha,S) \to (\prod _{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha, S) $ is measurable, but there is  $\alpha\in A$ such that $\pi_\alpha \circ Id$ is not measurable.